# Apache Flink - How to aggregate a list of strings with group by

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have joined a invoice table with a person table to group by Person Id.
Each person has one or more invoices and I want the invoice number as a list for elasticsearch to consume. I tried with Collect() and MULTISET without casting to array but on elasticsearch it creates a lot of mapping properties with invoicenumbers. Collect() returns a MULTISET are there any other functions that return an array? Any idea how to solve this?

```
CREATE TABLE ToElasticSearch (
    Id INT,
    INVOICENUMBERS ARRAY <STRING>,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'elasticsearch-7',
    'hosts' = 'http://localhost:9200',
    'index' = 'invoice'
);
```

```
INSERT INTO ToElasticSearch 
  SELECT
      p.Id,
      Cast(COLLECT(i.InvoiceNumber) AS ARRAY <STRING>) AS INVOICENUMBERS <-- how to create a list of InvoiceNumbers. This doesnt work.
  FROM
      Person AS p 
  LEFT JOIN Invoice AS i on i.PersonId = p.Id
  GROUP BY p.Id;
```

Comment: Not sure, but "CROSS JOIN UNNEST" and/or LISTAGG might help. Or you could write a user-defined aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks for the replay! I'll try user-defined function! Are there any example of creating a list of a group by with user-defined function?

Comment: There are examples in https://github.com/ververica/lab-flink-repository-analytics/tree/master/sql-functions/src/main/java/com/ververica/platform/sql/functions, and the explanations are at https://www.ververica.com/blog/simplifying-ververica-platform-sql-analytics-with-udfs.